# Selectively blocking internet access on windows, based on a pattern in the requested URL?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I need to block access by a certain Windows program to specific paths of a web site, but not to other paths on that site. Therefore I think using the hosts file won't be helpful for that.

Is there any way to block access to URLs matching a regular expression or even just those containing a specific substring?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) can do this, set it as proxy of Internet Explorer (or your application if it allows you to).

[Privoxy User Manual: The Path Pattern](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#AEN2786)